# "Using EnquireJS to trigger swapping image sources per media query" has no answers. Is it a bad question?

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question

I am trying to get an answer to [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/126016/using-enquirejs-to-trigger-swapping-image-sources-per-media-query).

Is the question wording bad?

Is the code bad?

Why has it not received any answers?

Thank you for any tips on how to improve the question so that it might get an answers.

Comment: See [Simon's guide for posting a good question](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/6429/31562) for tips on how to make your question easier to review and more attractive.

Answer (score 7):

The code looks reviewable, but the question has had 7 views in 8 days - it basically went completely under the radar.

Assuming you're looking for feedback on any & all aspects of the code, I've placed a +50 bounty on your question to draw attention to it.

The question isn't *bad* per se, but I do have a few ideas that could help:

- "I am also wondering whether to write {a} or {b}" - I'd remove that part; just show us the code that works and that you're using, if there's a better way then reviewers will tell you.
- "I am not entirely sure what the difference between the two is [...] is this correct?" - that's a rather specific question that's better asked on Stack Overflow, if it's not answered there already. On Code Review we don't explain to the reviewee what their code does, it's actually the reviewee's job to explain reviewers what their code is doing!
- If possible, include a *Stack Snippet* (edit, Ctrl+M) to make your code executable on-site instead of linking to a jsfiddle.
- Try to come up with a title that describes what your code does (swapping image sources, right?), in a way that's not too specific about how it's done - e.g. the "using enquirejs" part could probably be dropped, and a punny word play with "swapping image sources" could make the question more attractive from the main page.